# Facebook Like Box Disappearing

Tags: javascript, facebook

So whenever I add the first part of this script (everything from window.fbAsyncInit all the way to FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(100);), my Facebook Like Box doesn't pop up.

All I'm trying to do is remove the iframe scrollbars for the Like Box, which obviously has to be done in the submission to Facebook.

Why would adding this function at the top make the box disappear? How do I make the scrollbars go away?

I was trying to follow the instructions here:

http://clockworkcoder.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-removing-facebook-application-i.html

Here's my code:

```
<script>

 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
     appId: '388149184641600', 
     status: true, 
     cookie: true, 
     xfbml: true
    });


    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(100);


(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=388149184641600";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the closing bracket:

```
<script>

 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
     appId: '388149184641600', 
     status: true, 
     cookie: true, 
     xfbml: true
    });


    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(100);

 }; // HERE

(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=388149184641600";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
```

Comment: Doh. Thanks. Though this doesn't seem to get rid of the internal scrollbar either.

Comment: Should I open another question for how to make the resizing work?